# Simple post with facebook sdk 3.5 android remote_app_id does not match stored id

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

Hi i have used simple facebook example named HelloFacebookSample but when i tried to login it will not be login (my photo or name is not coming) or when i tried to click on button of post it always giving me error like

```
       Android Facebook key hash — “remote_app_id does not match stored id”
```

can any body help me how to solve this problem i am new in facebook integration

below is the screenshot with getting error like below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's generally because you have not put HashKey Value in facebook

if you are using mac pc than try with this

```
   keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

or if you are using windows pc then try to use this

```
   keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

if openssl is not fount on you pc the download first it with below link

http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_X64.zip

paste that hash key on your apps setting if you do not know how to do this please follow this below link

[image]

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/

now copy app_id of your facebook app

[image]

and paste in on string.xml file by  default there is an app id in "HelloFacebookSample" example replace it with your apps id

[image]

now run the example you will definitely post your answer

if you still getting an error it may be still error in your hash key you can get by another way also

just copy and paste below code on your "HelloFacebookSampleActivity.java" file's onCreate Method

```
         // Add code to print out the key hash
try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook", 
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

Now run your example you will get answer in logcat

for example

```
    12-20 10:47:37.747: D/KeyHash:(936): 478uEnKQV+fMQT8Dy4AKvHkYibo=
```

just copy this hashkey on your facebook app setting page and save it and re-run your app.

You will definately post :)

Comment: ya i have done it successfully i just forget to change app_id from string.xml thank you so much